# WLAN & Video Card Problem: MacBook Pro 7,1 Mid-2010

Tags: wireless, 12.10, nvidia

I would like to request your kind assistance in troubleshooting I have with my MBP running on Snow Leopard (10.6) but recently installed an Ubuntu 12.10 alongside the system.

Basically everything works out of the fresh install except for the two raised problems. I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I don't have any programming knowledge nor have the idea on using Terminal on both OSX and Ubuntu. I'm trying this to expand my knowledge and refreshen my work environment.

Here are the screenshots of the problem.

Broadcom WLAN driver is installed,just like what the [guide][1] for installation have recommended yet somehow the driver is not enabled. 
[Screenshot img of wlan problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82452639/Ubuntu%20Screens/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-15%2016%EF%80%A244%EF%80%A234.png)

While my nvdia 320m is also not being utilised well by Ubuntu. The [guide](http://www.yodi.sg/ubuntu-13-04-raring-installation-on-macbook-pro-7-1/) here says that I should install a propriety driver specifically the nvidia binary xorg driver for nvidia 310. somehow, when i open software sources, this driver installation doesn't show up. so i settled for an unstable open-source version.

Can you please help me through the process of where to download these drivers and installing them?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280